# Which is the official buffer size that Microsoft uses to copy files?

Tags: .net, windows

I would like to know which is the proper buffer size value to use in a .Net splitter/merger application that I'm developing, because to improve some **FileStream** I will set the same buffer size as **Microsoft** internally uses for copy operations in **Windows**.

I know this information exists and it is public because I seen this info in the past somewhere over Internet (maybe on **MSDN**) but I lost any references, if I remember good **Microsoft** uses 8 or 16 kb for buffer size, in any case is less than 1 MB for sure.

I'm looking for an official reference  where **Microsoft** allegates the value they uses, or else some kind of technically demonstrable answer (maybe using **Reflection**?), please avoid answers like "*I think they use X kb...*" because is not demonstrable.

Comment: Why would there be some official buffer size? Use whatever size you like. If you feel your performance could be better with a larger or smaller size, then try it and find out!

Comment: Thanks for comment but this does not solve my question, an excess of larger buffer size always will have a negative performance impact, I notmally use 1 MB for buffer size, but in the past I seen the official value that Microsoft uses (which is around 8 kb and 256 kb but I don't remember the exact value), I would like to find that official info again to follow the better programming practices for buffers (applying the same buffer size as Microsoft do).

Comment: It would solve your problem if you were to do performance testing of your application for various different buffer sizes. You would then find out what's best for _your_ application, which might be different from what's best for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to check the default buffer sizes used by specific stream implementations, by checking the implementation in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

The default buffer size for e.g. a [`FileStream`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,399) is 4096 bytes.
The default buffer size for [`Stream.Copy`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,53) implementations is 80 Kb.

A good practice when choosing a buffer size yourself is:

- Make it a multiple of the OS page size (generally 4096 bytes)
- If you have files / streams of a substantial size, make the buffer larger than a single OS page.
- Do performance tests to find a good size if this is a (potential) performance bottleneck.
- What is optimal on System A, may not be on System B with a different hardware/software configuration.